# How to open http://XYZ from my *own* tag in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I have ([abc] or [[abc]] or *abc ... ) in org-mode text, how can I link that to a command  `http://prosseek/wiki.php/abc?action=edit`?

I want to edit my own wiki page from simple org-mode link. The simple way would be manually input `[[http://prosseek/wiki.php/abc?action=edit][abc]]`, but I want to generate the first http part automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code snippet you're looking for:

```
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist
 '(
   ("mine" . "http://prosseek/wiki.php/%s?action=edit")
))
```

This will let [[mine:abc]] to jump to your link.