# How to call Emacs Lisp functions in Emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I have elisp function

```
(defun hello (param)
    ... )
```

how can I run the `(hello abc.txt)` with org mode? I learned [how to link http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035300/how-to-open-http-xyz-from-my-own-tag-in-org-mode) with `[[mine:...]]` tag. I expect similar way, something like `[[lisp:hello(abc.txt)]]` or something.

### ADDED

As this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668914/calling-vim-or-textmate-from-emacs) explains, I have `(runmate)` and `(runeditor (something))` elisp command.

It works fine with `alt-x runmate` in emacs, but when I run `[[lisp:(runmate)]]`, I get the following dialog box.

[image]

### SOLVED

It should have used `[[elisp:(runmate)]]`.

Comment: Gosh, Emacs has dialog boxes now? *shudder*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're close.  You need [[elisp:(hello "abc.txt")]]

[I'm assuming abc.txt is actually a string]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I got an error with it. Could you check my added post?

Comment: Well, functionally that's a *different* question (since you're now debugging an issue with calling runmate).  But, you might try: [[lisp:(call-interactively 'runmate)]]

Comment: The question should have been `How to call elisp function within org-mode?`. I tried [[lisp:..]] [[elisp:..], and [[lisp:('call-interactively)]], but all doesn't work. Does calling elisp function use the same method of calling [[lisp:...]]?